# What kind of type is this statement?

Tags: javascript

In javascript : is it legal ?

```
 var obj = [ id: '1', name: '' ];
```

type typeof(obj) return n/a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is a syntax error in JavaScript.  Probably it should be:

```
var obj = { id: '1', name: '' };
```

That's an *object literal*.  An array literal looks like this:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
```

You can put objects inside of arrays too:

```
var objarr = [ { id: '1', name: '' }, { id: '2', name: 'example' } ];
```

An empty object looks like:

```
var emptyObj = {};
```

An empty array looks like:

```
var emptyArr = [];
```

Comment: Nice and full answer.. you're the Jon Skeet of JavaScript. :-)

Comment: Whoa now that's a complement.  I'm blushing here. Also I left out arrays inside of objects :-)

Comment: And, of course, arrays inside of objects.  `var arrobj = { ids: [1, 2, 3], names: ['andy', 'barry', 'chris'] };`

Comment: Seriously, though, I find I do a lot of objects inside of objects.  Can build practically any kind of data structure.

Comment: You left out arrays inside of objects? Gasp. And you only showed one level of nesting. Double-gasp. -1 to you. (Not really, I clicked +1.)

Comment: @Pointy    ,why var emptyArr = [];
      alert(typeof(emptyArr)); 
**returns type object and not array ?**

Comment: Because @Royi Namir arrays **are** objects in JavaScript.  The "typeof" operator in JavaScript is pretty weak.  You might want to ask a separate question about that if you're uncertain about something.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want an object (looking at your variable name).
In that case it would be:

```
var obj = { id: '1', name: '' };
```

The [ and ] tokens are used to define an array and must look like:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

If you would like to know more about this in context to JSON, look at [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: Because array is not a 'type'...it's an array of types, like in this case an array of strings. The array itself is just an object.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets denotes an array, curly ones an object:

```
var obj = []; // short form to declare an array
var onj = {}; // short form to declare an object
```

Comment: So to explicitly answer the question: no, it is not legal because it's trying to use object literal syntax with the wrong style of brackets. It would be legal with curly brackets.